# Creating Read only access for ActiveMQ Web Console

Tags: web, jetty, activemq-classic

Is it possible to create read only users in ActiveMQ web console, i've surfed through so many websites and found no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer workaround mentioned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5388 . If you are referring 5.13.+ then make changes in jetty.xml like below snippet

```
<bean id="securityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="securityConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/api/*,*.jsp" />
</bean>
```

have made these changes and were able to have user who only has readonly access.